# JQuery change background of select every click

Tags: jquery, css, select, onclick, logic

Hello guys i'm trying to create a jquery function when he click the select button on the first time the background will change to white and if he click again it will change to blue vice versa

```
<select name="contact" class="changeBg">
     <option value="">Change!</option>
     <option value="">Changes!</option>
</select>

$('.changeBg').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [.toggleClass( className, switch )](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/#toggleClass-className-switch) to switch between two classes.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9KK65/)**

```
$('.changeBg').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('white blue');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/2wm9Q/)</kbd>

[.toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$('.changeBg').click(function() { //you can use change event
    $(this).toggleClass('BgColor');
});
```

**CSS**

```css
.changeBg { /* no need if your background is already white */
    background-color:#fff;
}
.BgColor {
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to toggle it with **name** like

```
$('select[name="contact"]').change(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('class1 class2');
});
```

For the both classes you can give background colors as like

```
.class1 {background-color:pink;}
.class2 {background-color:white;}
```

Even you can choose **class name** as like

```
$('.changeBg').change(function(){
     $(this).toggleClass('class1 class2');
});
```

But better you can switch or toggle 2different classes ratherthan the `changebg`.Because if you toggle that class then for the second time the change event wont be work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
        $('.changeBg').change(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('whileClass BlackClass');
        });
    });

    .whileClass {
        background-color: pink;
    }

    .BlackClass {
        background-color: white;
    }
```